# What is the difference between ADF Pipeline and ADF Data flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

What is the difference between ADF Pipeline and ADF Data flow? Why are sinks/sources supported in Pipeline and Data flow different? Is it possible to create a pipeline that reads data from source, filter, use joins and store data to a sink without a data flow? Please let me know.

Comment: Microsoft licensed DataBricks which runs on Apache Spark from DataBricks inc and package that up as the ADF Data Flow. Meanwhile you've got the rest of ADF, the Copy Data activity and so on, thats all Microsoft-built. So its two different things welded together.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pipelines are for process orchestration. Data Flow is for data transformation.

In ADF, Data Flows are built on Spark using data that is in Azure (blob, adls, SQL, synapse, cosmosdb).

Connectors in pipelines are for copying data and job orchestration. There are 90+ connectors available there that stretch across on-prem and other clouds.

We are always incrementally adding more connectors to data flows.

Comment: The same workload in Databricks seems to cost lower than ADF Data flows. I am applying simple transformations (cleaning data) in both systems, but ADF DF always ends up costing more.